# Is it "newspaper reports" or "newspapers reports"

Tags: word-choice, attributive-nouns

Somebody read many newspapers which presented a specific event in various ways.
How should I write, "newspaper reports", "newspapers reports", "newspapers' reports"?

> He recognized in the **newspaper(s) reports** a mixture of real facts and many fanciful stories which he readily detected as probably fabrications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oxford Learner's Dictionaries say newspaper proprietors, not newspapers proprietors.

So you can say a/the newspaper reports if they appear in a newspaper.

You usually say newspaper reports if they appear in multiple newspapers, though newspapers reports and newspapers' reports are not ungrammatical.

Comment: Apples and oranges. In the phrase "newspaper proprietors" newspaper is modifying proprietors to define what kind of proprietors. For the phrase "in the newspaper(s)" newspaper(s) is being used as a noun.

Comment: MaxW, It looks like you like to argue. I do not believe that the answer of Khan is wrong. It appears that newspaper is modifying reports to define what kind of reports because they can be: Facebook reports, TV reports, magazine reports. etc..

Comment: Not that I like to argue so much as I am trying to figure it out. Hmm... Now that I think about it if you use a possessive form (newpaper's or newspapers') then that form is necessarily modifying report.  (+1 to you Robert for a nifty way to shut down discussion..)

Answer (score 0):

Is it “newspaper reports” or “newspapers reports”

This is a dozzy!

*single article in newspaper*
“newspaper report”

*single article in multiple newspapers*
“newspapers' report”

*multiple articles in same newspaper*
“newspaper's reports”

*multiple articles in multiple newspapers*
“newspapers' reports”

report is singular and can be used for one report in a single newspaper of to indicate that multiple papers have each reported one time on the story.

newspaper's is possessive form for a single newspaper

newspapers' is the possessive form for multiple newspapers

Comment: The OP didn't ask about the difference between "report" and "reports", though, and I don't think this answer explains why these are correct.

Comment: I have met things like "Our Fifteen Most-Read Magazine Stories of 2015" that contains the group of words "magazine stories". So, "newspaper reports" might work in some circumstances. My specific question is what is the right combination for the particular example marked in yellow. I know the theory of the possessive (the ') but my example might not be in such a case.

Comment: @RobertWerner - You're clear that the reader read multiple newspapers. But did one or more of the newspapers have more than one story about the event? That would be "newspapers' reports." // There isn't any simple way to denote that the "Sun" had one article, the "Ledger" had two, the "Times" had three, and the "Herald" had one.